# jQuery animate problem

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to give my navigation button a colour change animation on hover.

I have `.menu-horizontal` and `.menu-vertical`. But for some reason, the animate function works well with `.menu-horizontal` but not for `.menu-vertical`.

The colour doesn't change for the vertical menu.

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu-horizontal ul li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ height: "31px", backgroundColor: "#3185b7" }, 600);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ height: "31px", backgroundColor: "#4fb3d3" }, 600);
    });

    $(".menu-vertical ul li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ height: "31px", backgroundColor: "#3185b7" }, 600);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ height: "31px", backgroundColor: "#4fb3d3" }, 600);
    });              
});
</script>
```

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but do you realise you can half your code? You don't need to write out the code twice, you can just put two selectors in: `$(".menu-horizontal ul li a,.menu-vertical ul li a").hover(function() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot animate `background-color` with jQuery alone.

> (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but `background-color` cannot be.)

Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties

**Option 1:** Set the `background-color` first using `.css()` and then animate the height.

**Option 2:** Use a [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) to facilitate `background-color` animation.